# How to separate table rows with horizontal line programmatic-ally in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Created a table layout programmatically .it looks like this.[image]

here i want to add horizontal line after each row,how to do it programmatically.
sample code to create table layout

```
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
TableLayout resultLayout = new TableLayout(this);
resultLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
resultLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
TableRow tablerowMostRecentVehicle = new TableRow(this);
tablerowMostRecentVehicle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

TextView textViewMostRecentVehicle = new TextView(this);
textViewMostRecentVehicle.setText("Most Recent Vehicle Details");
textViewMostRecentVehicle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
textViewMostRecentVehicle.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
tablerowMostRecentVehicle.addView(textViewMostRecentVehicle);
// ...
resultLayout.addView(tablerowMostRecentVehicle);
resultLayout.addView(tableRowRegistrationMark);
resultLayout.addView(tableRowMakeModel);
resultLayout.addView(tableRowColour);
resultLayout.addView(tableRowChasisNo);
resultLayout.addView(tableRowDateofFirstUse);
resultLayout.addView(tableRowTypeofFuel);
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
View view = new View(this);
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
resultLayout.addView(view);
```

Add this code after every table row.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add `view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));` to @dipali's answer:

```
View view = new View(this);
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
tablerowMostRecentVehicle.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = new View(this);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
tablerowMostRecentVehicle.addView(view);
```

I hope it's useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**R.drawable.row_border :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#99cc00" />

</shape>
```

then:

```
tbrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_borders);
```